# oncheckedchanged not firing for CheckBox when in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, oncheckedchanged

I'm trying to have a `OnCheckedChanged` event fire for an `asp:CheckBox` which is within a GridView. But when I put it into a GridView it does not fire the OnCheckedChanged in the code-behind.

If I put the same checkbox outside of the gridview, it's perfectly fine.

I've tried setting the function as a `RowCommand` and that doesn't work either.

Here is my checkbox:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="HoldBillingCheckBox" runat="server" key='<%# Eval("CustomerItemID") %>' Checked='<%# Eval("HoldBilling") %>' OnCheckedChanged="CustomerItemsGridView_CheckChanged" Enabled="true" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

It seems to me that this only occurs when you are trying to wrap the CheckBox with any view.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I've googled so many different solutions but nothing seems to work (they are mainly telling me to add `AutoPostBack` as `true`...or enableviewstate as true).

thanks in advance!

Comment: Far as can remember there should be a row loading event, basically the checkbox it's instantiated multiple times so need to wire up the handlers as each row loads. I think you will need view state on also

Comment: BTW - ASP-Classic is VBScript, not C#

Comment: I suspect you have a control ownership issue - since the control isn't owned by the page, it doesn't handle events for it either.

Answer (score 1):

If you are rebinding your gridview on each load of the page, then you are destroying the statefulness of the `CheckChanged` event. When you rebind your grid, it invalidates any controls that were in the previous "version" of the page.

You need to add `if (!IsPostBack)` as a conditional to prevent your GridView from rebinding.

Comment: you mean in Page_Load? But the event won't even fire. It doesn't even hit my break points at all within the OnCheckedChanged function.

Comment: You should post the code where your GridView is bound. If you're rebinding it on each post, then you're basically undoing any event bindings on any controls in the GridView.

Comment: technically..if i remove the autopostback and have no bind..it should still fire my function right? i removed postbacks and rebinds but it still doesn't fire my function

Comment: No,  you'll need postbacks for the control to perform an event. The rebind would be what is killing it.

Comment: yeah that's right i need the postbacks to fire server events..hmm but my databind is only done through page load...all i have for the gridview is the aspx and the datasource (you guys can probably tell i'm kinda new to this..so sorry for the questions)

Comment: Please post the code showing the Page_Load event. The Page_Load event fires every time a request occurs to the page (get or post). If you do not filter out "PostBack" requests, your Page_Load will rebind your gridview. This will destroy your original checkbox and all event transactions will be lost.